# Electric Turtle install fails on ARM, Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: robotic-arm, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not first time user and older ROSes installed many times. Now installing new clean environment on Pandaboard (ARM), Ubuntu 11.04, Electric Turtle it complains often about
missing dependencies. I prefer installing from source but also tried binary install. Both fail on ARM. There are no binary packages for ARM in repo I think.

Cannot copy-paste right now but it clearly looks up
stuff from ROS repository. Many things are missing but for example it looks for OpenCV-2.3.1 svn something which is not by default with Ubuntu. Old ROS installed OpenCV from tar.gz, new one looks for prepackaged binary and fails.

Tried adding related repository as "deb" and "deb-src" into sources.list but nothing went better. Yes I did apt-get update :).

I hope someone already knows simple way to solve this. Should be common problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11311/electric-turtle-install-fails-on-arm,-ubuntu-11.04/) by [tonuonu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1122/tonuonu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-09-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not all ROS packages are available in the ARM architectures.  See the [debbuild status page](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/electric.html) and look at the armel columns.  Anything white is available.

Each stack needs to be verified and updated to be armel compatible.  There are approximately 20 stacks which are building on armel at the moment.

One of the biggest limiting factors is that many of the system dependencies also are not released for the armel infrastructure. So beyond the core system you are going to need to build things from source.  Patches are appreciated to extend the number of stacks supported on armel.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonuonu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1122/tonuonu/) on 2011-10-23**:
http://www.ros.org/debbuild/electric.html does not list ARM anymore at all. Is ARM support dead completely?

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-10-04**:
I was going to suggest looking at the build log to see what was breaking, but it seems it's a 404 for some reason: http://build.willowgarage.com/job/debbuild-build-debs-electric-natty-armel

**Comment by [tonuonu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1122/tonuonu/) on 2011-10-03**:
So no solution except waiting?